# Can fixed effect absorb the anticipation effect?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I'm working on a research regarding natural disasters across counties in the US. I'm using these events as exogenous shocks for my Difference-in-Difference analysis. One assumption for the DiD is the absence of anticipation. However, some disasters are not random and can happen within a particular period time of the year (E.g., Wildfires in California often occur around June-July). I think this might cause some anticipation for these states/counties. My question is that how should I account for this potential anticipation? If I include county/state fixed effects will the anticipation effect be absorbed?

Thank you for your advice.